# Enzyme, How to access a component passed in props

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

What I am trying to test in `MyComponent` is the value of `checked` props of the `Switch` component which is a props of `FormControlLabel` component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

 (...)

 render() {
  return (
   <FormControlLabel
    name={`formControl`}
    control={
      <Switch
        name={`switch`}
        data
        checked={this.state.isChecked}
        onClick={this.handleChange}
        value={checked}
        />
    }
    />
  );
 }
}
```

I can access the `FormControlLabel` component like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);

wrapper.find('[name="formControl"]');
```

I tried to access the `Switch` component like this but it's not working:

```
wrapper.find('[name="switch"]');
```

How can I access the `checked` props of `Switch` component ?

API

- shallow

Version

- Enzyme: 3.3.0
- React: 16.2.0

Adapter

- enzyme-adapter-react-16

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I just found a solution:

```
expect(wrapper.find('[name="formControl"]').prop('control').props.checked).toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const controlComponent = shallow(wrapper.find(FormControlLabel).props().control);
expect(controlComponent.props().checked).toBeTruthy();
```